# How to change font-awesome's icon outside size of the container?

Tags: css, font-awesome

I am sorry that I really don't know how to describe the detail professionally!

I want to use font awesome's `icon-sort-up` like SO's `vote-up` icon, when I use it like this:

```
<i class="icon icon-4x icon-sort-down nomargin"></i>
```

I found the outside rectangle area is far bigger than the real triangle icon, in detail, take the following picture as example, the height `57px` of rectangle is much bigger than the height of triangle. I hope change the height of rectangle, what should I do for this?

[image]

Comment: You cannot change the height of rectangle except modifying the font itself or changing the font-size of `<i>` element. And you can use `position` and `top` attributes to change the position of the icon as described by @sdcr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that's part of the font features. But you could use something like `margin-top:-10px;` or `position:relative; top:-10px;` to get the positions you want.